# concatenate the result of loop in array in java

Tags: java, java-7

I declared the array before the for loop and now I want to concatenate the result of my for loop into the array. The following doesn't work and gives me error as "error: cannot find symbol".

My code is

```
for(int j=i; j<=arr.length-1; j++){             

    // checking for condition
    if (i<j )
    {
        int temp = arr[i]+arr[j];
        if (temp%sum==0) {
        System.out.println("Pair with given sum " +
                            sum + " is (" +temp+")");
            result[] += temp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to include in the foor loop, it comes just before the if statement

Comment: `result[] += temp` is patently incorrect.  Where was this array originally declared?

Comment: Declare result[] array and insert temp to some index of the array.
For example result[i] = temp. You can use an arraylist instead if you dont know what would be the final size of the result array.

Comment: yes Makota i had declared "int result[]"

Comment: okay Gihanmu i willl try that

Comment: can you explain how to use an array list?/

Comment: You will never get into the if statement.Inside the for loop you initialize j = i
and then you check if i < j, which will always be false.Then result[] += temp
is not valid because you do not specify the index of the array.

Comment: elaborate your question when you are posting. you did not mention in your question that "i need to add all the temp value in an array so that i could print out the count of that array.." , if you post it in your question , then it would be more easy to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You error is here

```
result[] += temp;
```

You need to provide an index to your array where it can store the value

Try something like this

```
result[i] += temp;
```

Also note that this will create an array with different `temp` values.

Plus in your `for` loop, you are doing `j=i` and then checking

`if(i<j)`

So your loop will run after 1 iteration, since the first time the condition will be false.

If you don't have to print the value `temp` and only the number of values, then you don't need an array at all.

You can simply create a variable

`int count=0;`

and then change your for loop to something like this

```
if (temp%sum==0) {
        System.out.println("Pair with given sum " +
                            sum + " is (" +temp+")");
            count++;
        }
```

Then print count.

If using an array is mandatory, you can print the length of array like

`result.length`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: hi @aradhana thanks for the help, but the thing is i need to add all the temp value in an array so that i could print out the count of that array

Comment: So you mean that you need to store (not add) temp values in an array and then at least you want to print the number of items stored in the array?

Comment: yes i want to store in temp values to array and print the number of items stored

Comment: please check the edit. Also, please mark this as the answer if it helped you. :)

Comment: the count did help me...thanks a lot :) but still storing in array hasn't worked...i don't understand how to index my array.

Comment: Your problem is solved for now. But if you want to learn about array, please join me here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112150/android-queries

Answer (score 0):

your code be something like this.. mention index of result in loop and declare it before use.
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean) to see why that error occur.

can you provide `int i` value ,so that we can help you in looping.

```
int result = new int[100] //give value according to your program.
for(int j=i; j<=arr.length-1; j++){             
// checking for condition
if (i<j )
{
    int temp = arr[i]+arr[j];
    if (temp%sum==0) {
    System.out.println("Pair with given sum " +
                        sum + " is (" +temp+")");
        result[j] += temp;
    }
}    `
```

Comment: this still gives me an error as "error: cannot find symbol
        int result = new result[100];"

Comment: sorry but i only need indexes for the elements stored by the loop....thecode you havewritten will just increase the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays do not work as you probably think.When you create an array like this

```
int x[10] = new int[10];
```

you can access the elements of the array like this:
for example if you want the 1st element `x[0]` the second `x[1]`(you statrt counting from 0 to the array length - 1).So what you have done here :

```
result[] += temp;
```

does not make sense.You sould always specify the index of the element that you wanna access(you probably want something like 
`result[index] += temp;`).

I hope i helped.

Comment: the loop won't work for the first iteration, which is what i want

Comment: oh you wanted it not to work ok then i will dlete that part.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is at line

```
result[] += temp;
```

You need to mention the array index in which you want to concatenate the result.
For eg

```
//your code goes here
.....
for (int k = index_of_resultArray_to concatenate; k < result.length; k++) {
    result[k] += temp;
}
```